# angularjs $scope variable inside jquery bind method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have been using Fullcalender directive in angularjs application. As I have been in the documentation there is double click handle exists in Fullcalender jquery plugin.

Here is the ref: http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=375#makechanges

There is a suggestion for the double click is that we should used eventRedner event handler for registering double event. As I did and got succeed but the problem is I wont be able to call $modal box inside bind method.

Here is the code.

```
$scope.eventPopup = function(event,element){
    console.log($scope);

    element.bind('dblclick', function(e) {
        console.log("double click" );
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: Drupal.settings.angularjsApp.basePath + '/ng_node/calender/popup',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            scope: $scope
        });
    });
};
```

Calender configuration:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        eventStartEditable: false,
        header:{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        //eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventRender: $scope.eventPopup

    }
};
```

Can any one suggest me what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show in jsfiddle ?

Comment: I have never used jsfiddle. But you want I can send you code for that reason. Problem is that in jQuery bind method I am unable to use Angular scope variable. Even though I have console.log (window) object I can access. Please advice if you know how to traverse angular scope variable via Window object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved that issue by using $apply() method in AngularJs.

```
element.bind('dblclick',function(e) {

        $scope.$apply(function(){
            console.log(event_date._d);
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: Drupal.settings.angularjsApp.basePath + '/ng_node/calender/popup',
                controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
                resolve:{
                    day: function (){
                        return event_date._d;
                    }
                },
                size: 'lg',
                scope: $scope
            });
        });

    });
```

$apply() function is used for jQuery binding.

Thanks